# Save and Display Image from DataBase

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, image, repeater

Not sure if this is close or not. 
I'm creating an image field within the database table Events using the code

```
public string EvtImage { get; set; }
```

For a start I'm not even sure if it should be a string. 
I am then trying to add the Image to the database by using the code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Events (AspNetUsersId,EvtName,EvtType,EvtDescription,EvtDate,EvtVote, EvtImage) values (@AspNetUsersId, @EvtName, @EvtType, @EvtDescription, @EvtDate, @EvtVote, @EvtImage)");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AspNetUsersId", userId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtName", eventName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtType", eventType.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtDescription", eventDescription.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtDate", datetimepicker.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtVote", 0);

if (eventImage.HasFile)
{
    var  imagename = eventImage.FileName;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtImage", imagename);
}

loadDatabase(cmd);
```

And once this is added I'm trying to display it within a `Repeater` in ASP.NET using the code

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterEvent">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="jumbotron">

            <h2><asp:Label ID="lblEventTest" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtName") %>'></asp:Label></h2>
            <h3><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtType") %>'></asp:Label></h3>
            <h4><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtDate") %>'></asp:Label></h4>
            <h4><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtDescription") %>'></asp:Label></h4>   
            <h4><asp:Label runat="server">Amount Attending: </asp:Label>
                <asp:Image ID="label6" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Bind("EvtImage") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtVote") %>'></asp:Label></h4>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="eventButtonTest" Text="Attending" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="EventVote_Click"/>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am creating the `Repeater` by using the code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-StudentMoneySaver-20160203040444.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-StudentMoneySaver-20160203040444;Integrated Security=True");

string query;
SqlCommand SqlCommand;
SqlDataReader reader;

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
//Open the connection to db
conn.Open();

//Generating the query to fetch the contact details
query = "SELECT EvtName, EvtType, EvtDescription, EvtDate, EvtVote, EvtImage FROM Events";
SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
//execute the query
reader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
//Assign the results 
repeaterEvent.DataSource = reader;
//Bind the data
repeaterEvent.DataBind();
```

Comment: How do you expect to get a *URL* out of a blob stored in the database? Besides, you don't show the code that *loads* the data from the database.

Comment: It seems you are saving image file name in db, that implies you must be saving image somewhere in hosted location, say `<Web_Root>/img/file.png`, if the above is true, then you just need to append image path to the one retrieved from DB.

Comment: What the path that you save in your DB?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just an update. I used varbinary in the end. I added the image to the database by using

```
  if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
        {
            Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            byte[] imgByte = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Events (AspNetUsersId,EvtName,EvtType,EvtDescription,EvtDate,EvtVote, EvtImage) values (@AspNetUsersId, @EvtName, @EvtType, @EvtDescription, @EvtDate, @EvtVote, @EvtImage)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AspNetUsersId", userId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtName", eventName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtType", eventType.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtDescription", eventDescription.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtDate", datetimepicker.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtVote", 0);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EvtImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imgByte;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

And displayed it in an image tag by using

```
            byte[] imgByte = null;
        con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Events", con);
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            imgByte = (byte[])(dr["EvtImage"]);
            string str = Convert.ToBase64String(imgByte);
            imageTest.Src = "data:Image/png;base64," + str;
        }
```

Front-End code:

```
<img runat="server" id="imageTest" src="imageIDtagName" />
```

Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: When you convert to Base64, it will result in large string, so it will slow down the app, better to go with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36548904/932584)

Answer (score 6):

Follow below steps,

In Database, you should have,

```
EvtImage image (datatype)
```

Declare as,

```
public Byte[] EvtImage { get; set; }
```

Change while save,

```
if (eventImage.HasFile && eventImage.PostedFile != null)
{
    //To create a PostedFile
    HttpPostedFile f = eventImage.PostedFile;
    //Create byte Array with file len
    EvtImage = new Byte[f.ContentLength];
    //force the control to load data in array
    f.InputStream.Read(EvtImage, 0, f.ContentLength);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtImage", EvtImage);
}
```

To display image, create handler as below, (change your table/columns as required)

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ShowImage" %>

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       Int32 empno;
       if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            empno = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
       else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

       context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
       Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(empno);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
       int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

       while (byteSeq > 0)
       {
           context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
           byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
       }       
       //context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }

    public Stream ShowEmpImage(int empno)
    {
 string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings     ["EmployeeConnString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        string sql = "SELECT empimg FROM EmpDetails WHERE empid = @ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", empno);
        connection.Open();
        object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Finally add asp image in aspx and add image url as,

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + id;
```

Let me know if you have any difficulties.

Comment: Thank you for this. When I try to save the image as a byte [] it shows in the database as a varbinary and when I change it to an image it still appears as a varbinary

Comment: Set image column datatype as image and save table.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and save it but it still converts the datatype back to varbinary even though I have saved it

Comment: I didnt understand when you say it converts data type, means it converts data type of database column?

Answer (score 2):

In the code behind write a method called `Collection()` to retrieve images and other fields as a List of Events like below (Also it is better to use `Using` statements):

```
public IEnumerable<Events> Collection()
{
    string address = "YourConnectionString";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(address))
    {
        con.Open();
        string qry = "select * from Events";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!dr.HasRows) yield break;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Events evt = new Events
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString()),
                    EvtName = dr["EvtName"].ToString(),
                    EvtType = dr["EvtType"].ToString(),
                    EvtImage = dr["EvtImage"].ToString()
                };
                yield return (evt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also a class:

```
public class Events
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EvtName { get; set; }
    public string EvtType { get; set; }
    public string EvtImage { get; set; }
}
```

Then to show this images you have two choice. You can either use `asp:Repeater` with an `asp:ObjectDataSource` like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterEvent" runat="server" DataSourceID="imgCats">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEventTest" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtName") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtType") %>'></asp:Label>
        <img src='<%# Eval("EvtImage") %>' alt="" width="50"/>
     </div>                  
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="imgCats" runat="server" SelectMethod="Collection" 
      TypeName="WebApplication1.WebForm8">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Just don't forget to change the `WebApplication1` in the `TypeName` to the name of your project and `WebForm8` to the name of your page.

**Finally**:To test this code you could create a new folder in your project and add some images to it then in your database in the `EvtImage` column store them like this:`\NewFolder1\yourfirstpicinnewfolder.png` and... . If you do this steps your images should be shown beside the other fields in the `Repeater`.

Answer (score 1):

If your image is being stored as a string database64 the database it should look like: "data:image/png;base64,dataImage" .
Otherwise you must convert your byte array (image in bytes) in database64 string and write to the bank so : "data:image/png;base64,dataImage".

Where DataImage will be the conversion data.
In asp.net you should to use Convert.ToBase64String(byte[]).

https://www.base64-image.de/tutorial

Comment: Thank you for this although I sort of understand it, I'm not sure how to implement it within my code

Answer (score 1):

Using a string is fine. I recommend you save the virtual path of the image in the database; meaning the path .net can resolve to a physical path on your server. E.g.

> ~/Images/myImage.png

where "Images" is a folder in the root of your .net project.

Then you can display the image by using

```
<asp:Image ID="label6" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# ResolveUrl(Bind("EvtImage")) %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

If Image save in your solution

```
<%# Eval("EvtImage", "~/{0}") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image file as string indicating the path of Image being saved in the server folder.

This is my implementation using MVC, you may need a little bit of modification, but I think most of the parts are just the same.

The View page:

```
<input id="EvtImage" title="Upload An Event Image" type="file" name="EvtImage" required="true" />
<img width="160" height="90" id="preview" src="#" alt="preview upload" hidden />
```

Use the ViewModel to store the Image :

```
 public HttpPostedFileBase EvtImage { get; set; }
 // other fields in your model
 ....
```

And then at the Controller class, bind the ViewModel at the place receiving your submitted form

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(YourViewModel model)
{
    var imgName = Path.GetFileName(model.EvtImage.FileName);
    var img = new Bitmap(model.EvtImage.InputStream);
    var imgPath = "";
    // combine file name of event image and the folder path in server
    imgPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Uploads/YourEventName"), imgName);
    img.Save(imgPath);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvtImage", imgPath);

    // the rest of your implementation
    ....
}
```